# How to Enable Multi-Touch screen on Dell Vostro 5470?

Tags: 13.10, screen, multi-touch, dell-vostro

I bought the new Dell Vostro 5470 with touch screen that supports multitouch (to 10 fingers). I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and it worked just touch the screen with one finger. Would enable multitouch but I could not, can someone help me? Someone has gone or is going through something?

Thank you!